# Using more than 4 cores with VCBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, multicore, vcbuild

I'm attempting to utilize all 12 cores of our build server, but am unable to specify /M12 and get all 12 cores working on the build. It appears as though /M4 is the limit. Is this true? Is there anything I can do to use all 12 cores in our builds?

I'm using the following command line to run the build:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe" /M12 C:\Projects\solution1.sln
```

The build treats it as if I specified one core based on how long the build takes to run and the initial output I receive is:

```
1) Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Release
```

If I use /M4 in the command line instead of /M12, the build goes much faster, and I receive this as the starting output:

```
5) Build started: Project: Project5, Configuration: Release
1) Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Release
2) Build started: Project: Project2, Configuration: Release
7) Build started: Project: Project7, Configuration: Release
```

I've tried not specifying the number of cores as well, but it treats it as if the machine has only one core or as if I had specified /M1.

I checked the system environment variable NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS and it is still set to 12.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

-Seth

Comment: Just curious, will it handle `/M9`?

Comment: Maybe you should try /MC (0xC=12)? ;-)

Comment: I've actually tried /M9 thinking it was only reading the first digit, but that isn't the case. It doesn't seem to do /M5 through /M9 and treats it as if I had typed /M1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on your particular project configuration that VCBuild *cannot* parallelize more than four projects for your particular build configuration.

For example, my understanding (feel free to correct):

1. VCBuild cannot parallelize *within*
   a project
2. VCBuild cannot parallelize
   two projects when "`ProjectA`" is a
   prerequisite (linked into)
   "`ProjectB`".  Rather, `ProjectA` will
   be built, and then `ProjectB` will be
   built, (which links in results from the previous `ProjectA` build). 
   However, "`ProjectA.lib`" can build in
   parallel to "`ProjectB.lib`", when
   they both are then linked into "`ProjectC.exe`"
   (although neither `ProjectA` nor
   `ProjectB` can be built in parallel to
   `ProjectC`).

So, depending on your projects, it seems possible that VCBuild only sees a maximum of four projects that are able to be built at the same time?

(NOTE:  IMHO, there is no fundamental reason for the two above limitations; Rather, my impression is that both limitations are due to historic internal/technical reasons, since VCBuild isn't really intended to be a "scalable build server".)